# How can I define a selection rule to use for Panels variants in code?

Tags: panels

I have some custom PHP code that I would like to use as a selection rule for about 30 different variants.  In the future, I may need to update this code, so rather than add the code 30 times, once for each variant, I would rather add it in code via a custom module so that I can more easily maintain it.

Is there a hook, etc. for adding Panels selection rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is internally called an "Access plugin".

Check my example on [How does one create a new Ctools plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/how-does-one-create-a-new-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc).

The advantage of this approach is that you can get rid of the evil [eval](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args).

Answer (score 4):

You can add Panels selection rules.

However, in your case, have you tried just calling a module function instead in your PHP code for the selection rule?

e.g, call a function defined in a module:

```
return my_module_selection_rule('foo');
```

instead of all the raw code there.

That way, it can be updated once in the module codebase.

I use that technique a lot for views php contextual filter handling code.

If so inclined, see

- `panels/plugins/task_handlers/panel_context.inc`

for the default selection rules plugin definition. and

- [ctools_context_handler_edit_criteria](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/ctools_context_handler_edit_criteria/7)

for the default form builder function for the selection rules.

Comment: nice recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by calling the function in your custom module. Lets say function is checkCondition() so you will have your code for selection rules return checkCondition(); and in the function you can set your condition to return true or false.

You can also do this for your content pane by adding visibility rule to it. Use php code for the same and call your checkCondition() function for it.