# Show panel content only if current user has purchased it

Tags: commerce, panels, flags

(Panels, Drupal Commerce, Flag, Rules)

I'm looking for a way to show a premium content type in a panel to users if they have purchased it (using Commerce). If they have not purchased it, the product display ('add to cart' button) is shown instead.

My current idea is to use Flag & Rules to automatically set a flag on content when purchased. However, I'm not sure if this is a sensible method, or whether it would work at all.

Any thoughts on this much appreciated!

Comment: "...panel content to users if they have purchased it..." - can you elaborate? Is the panel content a product?

Comment: Long ago there was a patch to do field level checks as selection rules (access plugins), I don't remember if it got merged into ctools or not. If not, you could find it in the issue queue. It was fairly rudimentary however in it's understanding of field content, but I believe it would be suitable for use as a simple flag check. The alternative, and most flexible way, would be to create a new access plugin. Check this related question any my answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58634/how-can-i-define-a-selection-rule-to-use-for-panels-variants-in-code