# Split the node edit form into multiple pages (preferably using panels variants)

Tags: 7, forms, panels

### The task

My goal is to split the node edit page with the main field forms staying on the default one (the add page itself or *mynodeurl*/edit), and some additional field forms on the other pages (e.g. *mynodeurl*/option & *mynodeurl*/otheroption).

I think the best way to do this (and the way I want it to work) would be using a couple of variants for the **node add/edit** page (**Panels Module**), with the url path's being filtered through the string: url path selection rules.

### The problem

I have no idea how to make the string url path selection rule work like that (I practically dont know anything how the string url path's selection rules work for the node (or node add\edit pages) at all, since I've only seen people implementing the url path based selection rules on custom pages and never on nodes).

### How I've tried to solve it

I've done some playing around setting url path's like: /option option */option nodetype/*/option etc. to the node template and the node add\edit form variants, the only thing that worked is when i set my main node view variant to trigger when: Current path is not "*/option" , and set the additional variant to trigger when Current path is "*/option", the exactly same thing didnt work for the node add\edit page. (see http://shot.faintrush.me/xfvu1c0aic.png <- this screenshot).

The only working variant is using the Node template page, and adding forms there doesn't work which makes it useless for me. (**If you know how to make forms work on the Node template page you'r also very welcome to answer here**).

Of course the */option is probably not the best thing to put there, it's just the only one I found that's at least a bit alive.

### Additional info

By default my url's work as I have explained here -> https://drupal.org/node/1993068 (i made those url aliases being created automatically but in a different way from using a pathauto + a custom token)
To make the links like siteurl.com/nodetype/25/edit work i use the sub-pathauto module (i have tried setting the sub-pathauto url depth to 2 and accessing siteurl.com/nodetype/25/edit/option with the settings on the screenshot above - didn't work).

### More additional info

I also tried to make this work by creating a custom Page with the **/node/%node/option** path and assigning **%node** the **Node edit form: node ID** context, but then I'm running into another problem because the Node id doesn't actually match the url path and there's no way for me to assign the right context to the node edit form - the unique content type node id that i'm using in urls (again, read the issue from the link a bit higher) is not to get by any token or variable, the url alias is just being generated once by the rules module.

I posted the same issue (written in a little bit different words) to the drupal official  website issue queue to the panels module but there seems to be no activity there for a couple of days so I'll give it a try here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: While I can sort of see how it would work, I don't think using multiple variants is a good idea. You're looking to break down a form into multiple steps, I don't see a good reason to tie that implementation to page manager. I would instead look for a generic single-to-multi-page-form-solution that would nicely "Just work" inside a single variant.

Comment: ||  I would instead look for a generic single-to-multi-page-form-solution that would nicely "Just work" inside a single variant. ||
Could you please go a little bit more detailed here?

And I'm not sure if you understood that but in my situation the addtional form pages are to be edited ONLY after the node is published with the default form (not just step by step: edited first forms page -> edited second forms page -> published), and it also SHOULD have a specific URL

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Your title says "Split the node edit form into multiple pages". I don't follow why my suggestion is not applicable to doing that. If you want to redirect the user to some specific page afterwards, you could do that. Maybe, when you say "Form", you don't mean that in the strict "A Form API form" sense, but in a "A collection of input fields" sense?

Comment: "I posted the same issue ... to the ... issue queue to the panels module but there seems to be no activity there" Yeah, I know. Every time I look at the queue I get annoyed that the documentation is so sparse, but I also don't want to take the time writing it.

Comment: You'r right, i do mean "a collection of input fields" by a "form", and I didn't necessarily mean that your suggestions aren't applicable, I just don't understand them. You told me to look for a "single-to-multi-page-form-solution" which at my current level of drupal knowledge doesn't tell me much (in a way of how to actually do it). Using panel variants on the other hand I have a clear image in my head how am i going to make it work the right way, the only thing I'm missing are the correct "string: url-path" selection rules, which I believe SHOULD exist.

Comment: If you'r interested enough I'd be glad to fully explain the context of my issue in skype.

Comment: Do they HAVE to be separate pages, or could they just have the APPEARANCE of separate pages? Because if the latter is true, then the [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module has a multi-page form widget in it's arsenal. If this is suitable then just give the word and I'll write a slightly more detailed answer.

Comment: For the thing i'm building now it would be much better if they would REALLY BE SEPARATE PAGES, so the multipage widget for Field Group isn't really something I'm looking for. Anyway, I just found a way to load the right node edit form context to a **node template page** panel variant which makes it possible to put working forms there -> make it want the way I wanted to. Going to put that as an answer in a moment.

Comment: I began writing an answer hours ago, but never posted it. Since you haven't posted anything yet, I did so now. If it's helpful or not I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Multistep Nodeform](https://www.drupal.org/project/msnf).

[image]

> For each step you can define which fields should be included in this
>   step. "Fields" includes core-fields like "Title", "Body" or "Authoring
>   information" as well as fields defined by other modules (e.g. Date).

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but there's a lot to cover, so here are some bits and pieces, and hopefully we can iron out something better from it.

For what it's worth, you refer to Panels, but it's Page manager that the question revolves around.

> I'm running into another problem because the Node id doesn't actually match the url path and there's no way for me to assign the right context to the node edit form

If you've come up with your own identifier scheme for you nodes, Page manager doesn't know about it. You can tell it, but implementing a new context type. See [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them).

> If you know how to make forms work on the Node template page you'r also very welcome to answer here

On node/%/edit, the edit form context is implicit, on node/% you can go to relationships and manually explicitly add it, but I don't see how that helps you. Plus using the node view to do node edit in general is weird.

Comment: || On node/%/edit, the edit form context is implicit, on node/% you can go to relationships and manually explicitly add it - that was the solution I mentioned 2 hours ago: adding a **Node edit form from node** relationship to a node/% template page panel. Yes, this way is kinda weird but in my current situation it does quite good. Creating a custom context type might also work but would require more time and more drupal knowledge that I've got. So, generally the thing I was looking for was quite simple, I just never really paid attention to the "Relatioships" tab in contexts.

Comment: I would still like to know if it is possible to split the node add\edit page panel into different multiple pages using variants filtered by the string: url-path selection rules. Thank you for your help efforts though!

Comment: Actually.. lol, it is possible, and it is quite simple. Just instead of using the "String: url path" path selection rules I could implement a PHP code based selection rule and make some simple parsing of the **current_path()** drupal function inside there.

Comment: You're obviously free to use it, but __PLEASE__ do yourself a favor and look at creating a new access plugin instead, which will do that for you, see link above. Use of the PHP filter should be __BANNED__.

Answer (score 0):

The **Field Group module** can split the node edit form into horizontal tabs for example, under each one of them you can select which fields to show.

Here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing the url, it tests the original path.
So if your node/15 has an alias of match/christmas and you want to make the match/christmas/options use another panel, you can add a 'PHP code selection rule' to your panel.
The way I've managed whas to print the args with dpm():

```
dpm(arg(0)); // node
dpm(arg(1)); // the node id, ex: 15
dpm(arg(2)); // options
```

Them I updated the code to:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'options') {
    return TRUE;
}
else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

And it worked =D

BUT putting php code isn't the best practice. SO I created a new "string URL path" selection rule with the path that now I know for sure that its being used.

```
node/*/options
```

Hope this helps =)