# Tracking an authenticated user's first visit to a Panels page and forward them to another page on subsequent visits

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite, nodes

I'm looking to expose authenticated user stat information to CTools / Panels.  Basically, I need to have a Panel variant that says: If the user has never visited the page, display this variant, if they have, display this variant.

Comment: Mostly out of scope for the question, but important to decide on, is "How do I keep track of which users have seen which page". I'd answer that question before I did anything else, as it will possibly be the largest constraint you need to take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You want an `access plugin`. See [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them) for an intro to how to build one.