# Panels page variant that targets a single node

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I am a little new to Panels, but I am using it to manage layouts for different content types and it is working out really well. However I want to be able to create a page variant that will only target a single node. Is there any way to do this based on the node's id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is use [Panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer).

Page manager itself can do it to, but I don't see a builtin rule to match on node ids. Copying an existing rule, such as `ctools/access/node_language.inc` would probably be the best way to solve that. See [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you already have the node override Panel enabled:

- Edit the panel page for the node override (node_view for node/%node)
- Make a new variant, enable selection rules
- For the selection rule, choose **String: Url Path**
- In the criteria, keep **Allow access on the following pages** selected
- In the textarea, add the internal node paths for this nid(s) you want.  To target nid 1234, use

  node/1234
- Configure the test of the panel as needed.

Just make sure this comes before any less-specific rules, like matches on content type.

Comment: Bah! How could I not have thought of that? +1

Comment: @Letharion I had to double check this on a few sites.  I haven't done this in a while, and was a little baffled that there isn't a node selection plugin that just lets you pick a node or enter a nid directly.

Comment: Please, check out another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356356/drupal-panels-use-variants-according-to-nid