# How to display different content in a panel page depending on device screen width?

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I have a custom panel page (admin/structure/pages). It has a sidebar region. I also defined a View with two content pane displays: "news-teaser" and "news-teaser2".

How to show "news-teaser" content pane in the sidebar region on desktop devices and "news-teaser2" on other devices?

Each content pane inside page has "Visibility rules". It would be great to add a rule which would return true only for desktop, but there is no such rule.

By the way, I have Adaptive Theme, so I chose adaptive layouts for the page, but this is not doing what I need. With adaptive layout, I can choose different layout for different devices. But I want basically the same layout for all devices, only with different content in it.

Comment: New visibility rules are quite simple to implement. See this Q: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337 and implement a new 'access' plugin.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how adaptive theme handles it, but this should be a simple css class on each pane.  I'll use the bootstrap responsive utility classes (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) as an example.  On the news-teaser pane add the class .visible-lg so it's only visible on large desktops.  You can add other classes as well.  On the news-teaser2 pane add the .hidden-lg class so that it shows on everything other than the large desktop.  Now this simply hides it from the user... if you don't want it to render in the markup at all then it's a much more complex solution.

Comment: @Craig - exactly, I don't want to render twice. Hiding is easy with Adaptive theme, but it would be a waste of bandwidth and server to always render two views and hide one.

Comment: @Letherion - I'll take a look at those plugins, they will be helpful. However, it will probably be more complex, because telling screen size is Javascript thing and not PHP, so it will need some ajax actions. I thought it would be more simple, but it's not.

Comment: @camcam - you're talking more about adaptive web design / progressive enhancement with that type of functionality.  At a high level that is the client telling the server info about itself (screen size, etc.) and then the server adapting based on that data.  I'm not exactly sure there are solid best practices for that yet.