# How do I put registration form in panel in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, blocks, panels, users

I would like to know how to put a registration form or any other form to make a new content type in panels. I know the first thing to do is to put the registration form in a block. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fucntion YOURMODULE_block_view($delta = ''){
  switch($delta){
    case 'YOURBLOCKNAME':
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_registration_form');
    break;
  } 
}
```

Or if you want to theme the block first, then register a theme hook in YOURMODULE_theme().

```
function YOURMODULE_theme(){
  $return['custom_user_reg']= array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'arguments'=> array('form'=> null),
    'template' => 'templates/form--user-registration',
  );
  return $return;
}

function YOURMODULE_block_view($delta = ''){
  switch($delta){
    case 'YOURBLOCKNAME':
    $form = drupal_get_form('user_registration_form');
    $block['content'] = theme('custom_user_reg', array('form'=>$form));
 }
```

Then in form--user-registration.tpl.php:

```
print render($form['email']);
print render($form['name']);
print drupal_render_children($form);
```

Of course you can add as much html in your tpl file as you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Form generic answer: There is no completely generic way to do this for "any form", because there is no way, for example, to query a form about the arguments it requires.
So for "any form", you need custom code.

While you're on the right path, putting the form into a block and then block into a page, really serves no purpose. What you want is a content type, and there's a fairly complete example in [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337).

Form specific answer: [Contextual administration](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_admin) actually happens to provide the user registration form as a content type, so you need no custom code at all.