# Any way of not to render the pane in panel using custom module?

Tags: 7, panels

I dont want to use `PHP visibility rule`  to add a custom condition but I want to hide a pane based on some condition. How can I do that?

Comment: You need an "access plugin". See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337 for an example.

Comment: Also, +1 on avoiding PHP visibility rules. :)

Comment: @Letharion why comment instead of answer?

Comment: @Molot because I feel this is a dup and should be closed as such. :) I could answer, but I'd just copy and paste half of my answer from the linked question.

Comment: @Letharion The link is for creating a ctool pane but I want only a visibility rule only or access plugin only.

Comment: Oh ok, I can create an access plugin too that works for every pane.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the top example is not relevant for what you want, both the access one is. :)

Comment: "but the access one is", of course. No worries, glad to help. Especially when it means someone is not using the php module ;) Posted an answer below, which is essentially my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a `access plugin`, those are how Page manager (and by extension Panels) control both access and visibility settings.

This question: [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337) has a lot more details and implementation examples.