# How to add byline into node view pane?

Tags: 7, theming, panels

Usually on node page we can see byline (*Submitted by admin on date*), but how to add that kind of info to the Panels pane?

It seems there is no single [`theme_node_submitted()`](https://api.drupal.org/theme_node_submitted) anymore in Drupal 7 therefore it's quite inconvenient to achieve that now.

Any ideas?

Related: [Submitted by byline in panes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1118898)

Comment: My preference is to manipulate the node view, and have Panels simply output the rendered entity. Would that work in your case?

Comment: @Letharion Could work, but currently I'm using separate panes for fields, so I don't need to render the whole node again (because it would duplicate the content). The only way would be to trim/manipulate whole node (as you suggested), but I think it would be waste of resources to render the whole node only to get specific part from it. I'm sure that there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe a php pane with code stolen from the template file?

Comment: @kenorb For what it's worth, on the semi-large project where I've done that, individual fields placed with Panels, I ended up regretting it when it came time to try to cache things better. Since then I've decided that I generally want to avoid placing individual fields.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a new specific content pane for the byline, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337#33337 for examples. Just _please don't_ do what Darvanen suggests. php module. \*shrug\*. As if we need _more_ security holes.