# Passing PHP filtered arguments to Panel and View Pane

Tags: panels

I have been able to pass URL parameters to a Panel and from there to a View Pane inside the Panel.
However, I must pre-proccess the URL data with PHP. I have only been able to use Visibility rules with PHP in the View Pane but cannot manage to insert the PHP code in order to pass the specific PHP-modified values.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to DA! I posted an answer below for how to do this without the php filter. The PHP module is a huge [security issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args), so I tend to avoid recommending it. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

By far the best way to do this is to provide your own context.

See [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337#33337) for how ctools plugins work, and adapt one of the examples to a context plugin instead.

That way you can decide what data is passed into Panels, and on to the individual panes in a safe manner.