# Dynamic RSS Feed in View

Tags: 7, feeds

Passing a context from the panel to the view.

Need the view to accept the context and then consume an RSS feed.

For example: visiting /stock/MSFT would pass in MSFT to the view. The view would then hit http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/industry?s=MSFT and consume that RSS content.

I know you can consume a *static* feed with the Aggregator or Feeds module but what about a dynamic one. Any ideas?

**Thanks!!**

Answer (score 1):

For those of you interested -- the only way I could figure out how to solve this was with writing a custom cTools plugin (See: [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them)).

In that plugin I created a block and placed it in the panel.

I used Magpie RSS for the parsing/fetching of the feed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a contextual filter to your view (in the Advanced column).

If you have added a feed with the title MSFT, then add the contextual filter 'Aggregator feed: Title'. In the second step, configure the filter value to 'Provide default value' and type is 'Raw value from URL'. Then you can navigate to /your-page/MSFT.

Comment: So for 200 stocks, I'd have to input each feed individually?

Comment: The panel passes the stock name to the view already (It's a taxonomy page override). The view will then take that stock name, grab the URL and display it accordingly.