# Panels visibility rule: Hide if value is in the query string

Tags: panels

I am trying to use a visibility rule in Panels to hide a block based on whether the query string has a parameter (`value=5`) or not.

Panels provides a **String: URL path** visibility rule by default, but this seems to only work for the URL path, not the query string.

Is there a way to add a condition to show/hide the block based on one of the parameters in the query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PHP code is not recommended unless absolutely necessary. You never want to store the PHP code in database, you do that in the modules :-)

I would recommend you to write an ctools access plugin for the same; check the logic there and give access to users accordingly.

Benifits:

1. The code is more maintainable, and can be version controlled.
2. You could reuse the same visibility rule throughout the site wherever necessary.

Please check my answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/159451/6461), for an example of a working access plugin.

Comment: Yes, as you saw, I had already started working on an access plugin to do this, and I will post it when I get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the ctools access plugin I made based on [AjitS's advice](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159417/define-a-panels-visibility-rule-programatically/159451#159451):

It checks for whether the 'd' parameter in the query string has a numeric value or not.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Plugin to check whether the value matches the query string
 * https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337#33337
 */

/**
 * Plugins are described by creating a $plugin array which will be used
 * by the system that includes this file.
 */
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t("Check for proximity in query string"),
  'description' => t('Returns FALSE if the value is in the query string'),
  'callback' => 'mymodule_checkproxquerystring_ctools_access_check',
  'settings form' => 'mymodule_checkproxquerystring_ctools_access_settings',
  'summary' => 'mymodule_checkproxquerystring_ctools_access_summary',
);

/**
 * Settings form
 */
function mymodule_checkproxquerystring_ctools_access_settings($form, &$form_state, $conf) {
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Check for access.
 */
function mymodule_checkproxquerystring_ctools_access_check($conf, $context) {
  if (isset($_GET['d']) && (is_numeric($_GET['d']))) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else {
    return TRUE;
  }
}

/**
 * Provide a summary description.
 */
function mymodule_checkproxquerystring_ctools_access_summary($conf, $context) {
  return t('Proximity in query string');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a PHP code selection and use $_GET['q'] to parse the parameters.

Comment: As mentioned by Ajits, executing php code that is stored in the database is not recommended and dangerous because it's very hard to debug